# Combinatorics: Inclusion and Exclusion Principle: Arranging balls

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I need to calculate the number of possibilities of arranging 9 (numbered) balls in a line when:

-balls 1-3 are not in places 1-3.

-balls 4-6 are not in places 4-6.

-balls 7-9 are not in plcaes 7-9.

I managed to calculate the possibilites of each of the conditions alone:

${6\choose3}6!3!$

I want to use the  Inclusion and Exclusion Principe but i'm having trouble calculating the possibilites of two or more conditions accuring together. 
Any help with that?

Thanks.

EDIT: typo, balls 7-9 are not in plcaes **7-9**.

Comment: Can balls 1-3 be arranged in places 1-3 but not in their *own* place, e.g. 312 ?

Comment: And did you mean to say "balls 7-9 are not in places 7-9"?

Comment: I meant that balls 1-3 can be placed in any place except the first, second and third place.

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume you meant the third condition to read "balls 7-9 are not in places 7-9" (if you really meant that they are not in places 4-6 the problem is easy since you'd know that balls 1-3 went to 4-6 and the other 6 balls can go freely into the remaining 6 places). I am also assuming that you meant your conditions to read, e.g., "None of the first three balls can appear in any of the first three places."

What follows has a reasonably high chance of arithmetic error, but the method should be sound.

Let's call the groups "1-3" etc. triples.

Look at where balls 1-3 can go.  We see that there are two cases:  either they take up an entire triple (4-6 or 7-9) or two of them go to one and one to the other.  We'll count both cases and add.

Case I:  balls 1-3 all go to the same triple.

Say, for definiteness, they went to 4-6.  Then we know that balls 7-9 must go to 1-3 and 4-6 must go to 7-9.  Thus there are $(3!)^3=216$ ways to do it.  Of course it is the same if the first three balls went to 7-9 so this case contributes 432.

Case II. one of 1-3 goes to one triple and the other two go the other triple.

We note that there are 3 ways to choose a single slot from one of the two available triples and 3 ways to choose two slots from the other so there are $2*9=18$ ways to choose one slot from one triple and two from the other.  Now fix one.

For definiteness say that we choose slots 4,5,7. Of course there are 6 ways to arrange the three balls in those three slots. We know that slot 6 must be taken by one of balls 7-9.  3 ways to choose that. We also know that the slots 8,9 must be filled by two of the balls from 4-6.  There are 6 ways to do that.  We are left with three balls (two from 7-9 and one from 4-6). These must go to slots 1-3 and there are 6 ways to arrange them there. Thus this particular case contributes $3*6*6*6=648$. As we said there are 18 instances of Case II so case II contributes $18*648 = 11,664$

the two cases are additive so the answer is $432+11664=12,096$.  (barring arithmetic error, of course)